# Start and stop hiveserver2

Tags: php, hadoop, hive, thrift, bigdata

I connect to hive by php thought thrift so I want start hiveserver2 but if I using hive command to start hiveserver2

```
hive --service hiveserver2 --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.port=10000 --hiveconf hive.root.logger=INFO,console
```

I always need stop hiveserver2 by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

I find a new way by start by service command I was try

```
service hive-server2 start
service hiveserver2 start
```

but I get error: `hiveserver2: unrecognized service`

Can anyone help me how to start it with service command?

Comment: You can always run hiveserver2 in background by below command  nohup hive --service hiveserver2 & , this way you don't have to do Ctrl+C to stop and  service will be  running in background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always run hiveserver2 in background by below command

nohup hive --service hiveserver2 &

Comment: i need it alway running and stop when i want